# Is it possible to configure pacemaker with a configuration file?

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I'm trying to configure pacemaker with a config file (that I can automatically generate and then ask pacemaker to "reload").  But all the examples that I see are for command-line commands or the interactive editor.  (I'm running Ubuntu).

The command-line approach is something like [this](http://linuxlasse.net/linux/howtos/Pacemaker_and_Corosync_HA_-_2_Node_setup):

```
crm configure primitive VIP ocf:IPaddr2 params ip=10.0.2.200 nic=eth0 op monitor interval=10s
```

While the interactive mode is something like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClusterStack/Natty#HA_Virtual_IP_Address):

```
sudo crm configure
And then we add the res_ip resource:

crm(live)configure# primitive res_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip="102.169.122.254" cidr_netmask="24" nic="eth0"
crm(live)configure# commit
crm(live)configure# exit
```

But I want a static config file that I can update and reload.  Something like the `/etc/ha.d/haresources` file that heartbeat uses.  Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely. Create a configuration file (named 'cib.txt', in our example) with the same syntax you've used in your example commands:

```
primitive VIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip=10.0.2.200 nic=eth0 \
    op monitor interval=10s timeout=20s \
    op start interval=0 timeout=20s \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=20s
```

Then you can load that file using the following CRM shell command:

```
# crm configure load update cib.txt
```

or completely replace the configuration:

```
# crm configure load replace cib.txt
```

NOTE: You can export the configuration from a cluster, for use on a new cluster or for backup purposes, with the following command:

```
# crm configure show > cib.txt
```

WARN: Be sure to cut out anything specific to the original cluster if you intend to load it elsewhere (node id's, dc-version, last-lrm-refresh, etc).

Comment: Awesome!  All three commands that you explained are great!

Comment: This only works for pacemaker < 1.1.18, there is no "crm" now.

Comment: 'crmsh' (the crm shell) used to be a part of Pacemaker, but was split into it's own project long ago. You can still get from here if you prefer it: https://crmsh.github.io/

Comment: Is there a a version of this command for the newer management shell? cman, pcs?

Comment: Or could I load crmsh, and just use it for this purpose?

Comment: You can install and use both crmsh and pcs to manage your Pacemaker config without causing issues. SUSE packages crmsh for the more popular distros here: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=network%3Aha-clustering%3AStable&package=crmsh